# Meu site não encontra os arquivos Bootstrap e Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3, jquery-datatables, microsoft-azure

Criei um site `ASP.NET MVC` com `Code First` e fiz o primeiro `publish`  da aplicação, o Banco de Dados e o Site foram criados, o problema é que o site não encontra os arquivos `css` e `Jquery` do `Bootstrap` e da pastas Scripts.

Eu imaginava que  na primeira publicação do site já contemplava a transferência desses arquivos `css` e `JavaScript` do `Bootstrap` e da pasta Scripts automaticamente.

Estou procurando aqui no Azure onde fica a pasta root com os arquivos compilados e não encontro.

**Arquivo BundleConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/numeral").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/numeral/numeral.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moneymask").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.moneymask.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables-1.10.12/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables-1.10.12/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.min.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/inputmask").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/inputmask.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/inputmask.extensions.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/DataTables").Include(
       "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.12/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
       "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.12/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js",
       "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.12/extensions/AutoFill/js/dataTables.autoFill.min.js",
       "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.12/extensions/AutoFill/js/autoFill.bootstrap.min.js",
       "~/Content/DataTables-1.10.12/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js",
       "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"));
    }
```

**Ocorre erro 403 forbiden**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Este é o arquivo de Layout**

Obs: Fica na pasta

> \Areas\Administrativo\Views\Shared_AdministrativoLayout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Administração</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <div class="navbar-header"></div>
                @Html.Partial("_MenuPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Para uma View que está localizada por exempo em:

> \Areas\Administrativo\Views\Cliente

Faço assim:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CLIENTE";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Administrativo/Views/Shared/_AdministrativoLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Executando o projeto funciona perfeitamente, porém quando faço o deploy a aplicação não acha os arquivos jquery, css e do bootstrap e , como podem ver eu referêncio o arquivo bundle assim: `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`

Comment: No seu pc funciona porém na web não funciona?

Comment: Sim no meu pc funciona e acabei de encontrar o diretório root  no Azure e todos os arquivos do Bootstrap e Jquery estão lá mas não funciona.

Comment: Verificou se está linkando corretamente?

Comment: O site carrega no browse, porém o site não encontra os arquivos bootstrap e jquery é isso que você está perguntando ?

Comment: Poste o conteúdo do arquivo `Bundle.cs`

Comment: @jbueno eu adicionei o arquivo Bundle na pergunta, localmente funciona.

Comment: Abra o devtools do seu navegador - pressionando `F12` - vá na aba Network e veja quais requests está em vermelho. Principalmente os com código `404` que serão os não encontrados.

Comment: @Thiago Lunardi adicionei uma imagem do navegar o erro é o **403**

Comment: @AdrianoSUV pdoeria me informar se você usa o _BootrstrapLayour.basic? Se sim, todas as referências estão lá? Tive um problema exatamente igual ao seu, no caso quando eu utilizava o Script.Render eu passava por parâmetro ("~/Scripts") e no bundle config estava ("~/js") o que causava esse erro.

Comment: @Leonardo Coelho onde fica esse arquivo ? Procurei em minha Solution e não encontrei e acredito que meu projeto não usa esse arquivo

Comment: @AdrianoSUV então provavelmente você não use mesmo. Normalmente é nele que você define o Layout Básico do seu site como menu de navegação e rodapés que são fixos para todo o site. Em algum lugar você tem que referenciar, tente procurar no seu projeto por um "RenderSection" ou "Scripts.Render" ou algo assim. Pode ser que você encontre.

Comment: SIm @Leonardo Coelho eu uso o `BundlesConfig.cs` que fica na pasta App_Start que é padrão para os projetos e nas Views eu referencio assim `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`, no entanto tenho uma observação: na tela de `Login`  o sistema encontra os arquivos do BootStrap e Jquery, o problema é após o Login do usuário que é redirecionado para uma `Area/Administrativo/Home`.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV você usa alguma view para criar o Layout Básico? Se sim, poderia postar aqui a parte aonde renderiza os Bundles?

Comment: Sim @Leonardo Coelho , adicionado na pergunta.

Comment: Mais duas dúvidas, você tem certeza que esses arquivos estão adicionados no projeto? Outra coisa, tenta alterar a linha de Styles Render e colocar isso.



    <link href="@Styles.Url("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: Verifique se os arquivos fazem parte do projeto.

Comment: Você consegue acessar esses arquivos pela navegando pela URL?

Answer (score 0):

Alterei o nome do **StyleBundle**  de: `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")`
para `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/Admin")`
Obrigado @Leonardo Coelho pelas sugestões.

Comment: Hum... resposta superficial ainda. Me confirma se já não existia a pasta `~/Content/css`. Vai ver que foi esse o conflito.

Answer (score -2):

Eu tive o mesmo problema também no meu projeto em .NET Core. Enquanto que o projeto aponta corretamente pro arquivo bootstrap.css, o site carregado no servidor aponta para o endereço abaixo:

```
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Detalhe: o servidor onde o site foi hospedado foi no UOL Host, que não suporta esse framework, porém o .NET Core te dá opção de implantação autossuficiente. Se alguém por acaso já enfrentou problema parecido, por favor, comente. Obrigado.